# Show single product prices with and without VAT in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, tax

I'm trying to show price with and without VAT on every Single Product page in a WooCommerce store.

I already done it for variable products with the script below, thanks to the `WooCommerce_available_variation` hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'my_variation', 10, 3);
function my_variation( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    $data['price_html'] = "<bdi><span class='inc-vat-price'></span>" . woocommerce_price($variation->get_price_including_tax()) . "</bdi><br>";
    $data['price_html'] .= "<bdi><span class='ex-vat-price'>Tax Free - </span>". woocommerce_price($variation->get_price_excluding_tax()) . "</bdi>" ;
    return $data;
}
```

Instead, for a Single Product, I haven't found any solution.

By modifying the Price.php file of the Single Product in WooCommerce, the price without Vat is repeated also in the variable products. In this case I have used the code:

```
$product->get_price_excluding_tax()
```

What is a possible solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your actual code for `WooCommerce_available_variation` **is really outdated** since a while:

- The function `woocommerce_price()` is replaced by `wc_price()` function
- The method `get_price_including_tax()` is replaced by `wc_get_price_including_tax()` function
- The method `get_price_excluding_tax()` is replaced by `wc_get_price_excluding_tax()` function

Now you could have instead **a unique function for simple products, variable products and product variations** html formatted prices, that will handle also on sale price, displaying prices with and without taxes.

So the following will replace your code and will work for simple products, variable products and product variations displaying including and excluding prices in a custom formatting way *(as you did on your code)*, **on single product pages only**:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'display_prices_incl_and_excl_taxes', 100, 2 );
function display_prices_incl_and_excl_taxes( $price_html, $product ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    // On single product pages only (and not on any product loop)
    if( isset($woocommerce_loop['total']) && $woocommerce_loop['total'] == 0
    && isset($woocommerce_loop['total']) && empty($woocommerce_loop['name']) ) {

        // For simple products and products variations
        if( $product->is_type('simple') || $product->is_type('variation') ) {
            // On sale products
            if( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
                $regular_price_incl_tax = wc_get_price_including_tax( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) );
                $price_incl_tax_html    = wc_format_sale_price( $regular_price_incl_tax, wc_get_price_including_tax( $product ) );
                $regular_price_excl_tax = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) );
                $price_excl_tax_html    = wc_format_sale_price( $regular_price_excl_tax, wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product ) );
            }
            // Not on sale
            else {
                $price_incl_tax_html = wc_price( wc_get_price_including_tax( $product ) );
                $price_excl_tax_html = wc_price( wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product ) );
            }
        }
        // variable pproducts
        elseif( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
            $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );

            if ( ! empty( $prices['price'] ) ) {
                $act_keys = array_keys($prices['price']);
                $reg_keys = array_keys($prices['regular_price']);

                $min_price_incl_tax = wc_get_price_including_tax( wc_get_product(reset($act_keys)));
                $max_price_incl_tax = wc_get_price_including_tax( wc_get_product(end($act_keys)));

                $min_price_excl_tax = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( wc_get_product(reset($act_keys)));
                $max_price_excl_tax = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( wc_get_product(end($act_keys)));

                $min_reg_price_jncl_tax = wc_get_price_including_tax( wc_get_product(reset($reg_keys)));
                $max_reg_price_incl_tax = wc_get_price_including_tax( wc_get_product(end($reg_keys)));

                $min_reg_price_excl_tax = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( wc_get_product(reset($reg_keys)));
                $max_reg_price_excl_tax = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( wc_get_product(end($reg_keys)));

                if ( $min_price_excl_tax !== $max_price_excl_tax ) {
                    $price_incl_tax_html = wc_format_price_range( $min_price_incl_tax, $max_reg_price_incl_tax );
                    $price_excl_tax_html = wc_format_price_range( $min_price_excl_tax, $max_reg_price_excl_tax );
                }
                elseif ( $product->is_on_sale() && $min_reg_price_excl_tax === $max_reg_price_excl_tax ) {
                    $price_incl_tax_html = wc_format_sale_price( wc_price( $max_reg_price_incl_tax ), wc_price( $min_price_incl_tax ) );
                    $price_excl_tax_html = wc_format_sale_price( wc_price( $max_reg_price_excl_tax ), wc_price( $min_price_excl_tax ) );
                }
                else {
                    $price_incl_tax_html = wc_price( $min_price_incl_tax );
                    $price_excl_tax_html = wc_price( $min_price_excl_tax );
                }
            }
        }
        if ( isset($price_incl_tax_html) && isset($price_excl_tax_html) ) {
            $price_html  = '<bdi><span class="inc-vat-price"></span>' . $price_incl_tax_html . '<bdi><br>';
            $price_html .= '<bdi><span class="ex-vat-price">'. __("Tax Free") . ' - </span>' . $price_excl_tax_html . '<bdi><br>';
            $price_html .= $product->get_price_suffix();
        }
    }
    return $price_html;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

This code will not handle variable product price range.

Comment: LoicTheAztec if we want to reverse the display order excl comes first incl comes next to it and you just highlight so I try to do it?